# bash variable expansion not working as expected

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Everything **looks** right, and pasting the "echo" output into the aws command works as expected.  However, when using the variables on the command line, aws complains about an unclosed delimiter, even though there is (or at least *seems to be)* a terminating delimiter.

```
QF1="'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, " 
QF2="SecondaryAvailabilityZone]'"

echo ${QF1}${QF2}
'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, SecondaryAvailabilityZone]'

$ aws rds describe-db-instances \
    --query 'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, SecondaryAvailabilityZone]' \
    --output=table
-------------------------------------------
|           DescribeDBInstances           |
+--------------------------+--------------+
|  copy-20210720           |  None        |
|  uis-clitst-rds-east-db1 |  None        |
|  uis-dev-rds-east-db1    |  None        |
|  uis-intst-rds-east-db1  |  us-east-1c  |
|  uis-prod-rds-east-db1   |  us-east-1b  |
+--------------------------+--------------+

aws rds describe-db-instances --query ${QF1}${QF2}

Bad value for --query 'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier,: Bad jmespath expression: Unclosed ' delimiter:
'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier,
^
```

Comment: Related: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Comment: also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting Look at the string it shows in the error message, it's `'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier,`. (Also, try `echo foo      bar`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
QF1="'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, " 
QF2="SecondaryAvailabilityZone]'"

# ...

aws rds describe-db-instances --query ${QF1}${QF2}
```

Take note of the [list of expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) the shell will
perform  *first* and *then* launch `aws` -- because you're not quoting the variables on the last line, you are subject to the effect of [3.5.7 Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting)

The command used to launch aws will be (angle quotes added for illustration)

```bsh
aws rds describe-db-instances --query «'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier,» «SecondaryAvailabilityZone]'»
# ....................................^......................................^.^...........................^
```

The error message is telling you the truth.

Do this instead:

```bsh
aws rds describe-db-instances --query "${QF1}${QF2}"
# ....................................^............^
```

Braces are not a substitute for quotes.

Comment: `aws` does not like double quotes in it's parameter list; only single quotes.

Comment: The shell will remove the double quotes before launching aws. But they are crucial to build the string properly. You may need to remove the literal single quotes from the QF variables.

Comment: Understanding shell expansions is critical to writing bug-free shell scripts. Do spend some time reading the links I gave you.

Comment: Thanks @ilkkachu, I've updated the wording a bit

Comment: OP likely also needs `QF1="DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, "` or `QF1='DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier, '` that is, the `'` are not meant to be part of the argument passed to `aws`.